# Django Model Formset Pre-Filled Value Problem

Tags: django, forms, django-forms

i'm trying to use model formsets with Django. When i load forms template, i see that it's filled-up with previous values. Is there a caching mechanism that i should stop, or what?

Thanks for your help, here is my code:

models.py

```
class FooModel( models.Model ):

    a_field     = models.FloatField()
    b_field     = models.FloatField()

    def __unicode__( self ):
        return self.a_field
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms.models import modelformset_factory

FooFormSet = modelformset_factory(FooModel)
```

views.py

```
def foo_func(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        formset = FooFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix='foo_prefix' )

        if formset.is_valid():

            formset.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect( '/true/' )

        else:

            return HttpResponseRedirect( '/false/' )

    else:

        formset = FooFormSet(prefix='foo_prefix')

    variables = RequestContext( request , { 'formset':formset , } )

    return render_to_response('footemplate.html' , variables )
```

template:

```
<form method="post" action=".">
{% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
   <table id="FormsetTable" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
       <tbody>
           {% for form in formset.forms %}
           <tr>
              <td>{{ form.a_field }}</td>
              <td>{{ form.b_field }}</td>
           </tr>
           {% endfor %}
       </tbody>
   </table>
   {{ formset.management_form }}
</form>
```

Comment: It's filled up with previous values? like the last item you entered into the form? It definitely shouldn't do that with the code you've written. You're initializing the form from scratch -- there is no data. Can you give more details on what values are appearing? You could always try throwing in the never_cache decorator but that's super odd.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main problem here is in line:

```
formset = FooFormSet(prefix='foo_prefix')
```

When you instantiate FooFormSet() the `queryset` used to generate the forms is (by default):

```
FooModel.objects.all()
```

So, if you already have some FooModel() in your database they will be listed. In this case you can use:

```
formset = FooFormSet(prefix='foo_prefix', queryset=FooModel.objects.none())
```

You can see more information about this in Django's Documentation:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-queryset